# vscode 1.82.1: Output from the debug console is being directed to the integrated terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, terminal

After updating to version 1.82.1, all output from the debug console is being directed to the integrated terminal, making the debug process slower.

I'm run Python FastAPI and when typing print("hello") in the debug console, the output is output to the terminal and all this with a high delay.

Is possible disable this redirect?